# Writing nagios service acknowledgement to system file

Tags: linux, nagios

I use nagios heavily to monitor many servers and services and rely on it daily.  As of right now all services get written to the system log (currently CentOS 6.9) and sys admins get notified when services are failing.  However, services that have been acknowledged still write to the system log and so I am constantly being notified by services that I have already acknowledged.  Is there a way to add ACKNOWLEDGED to the log entry so that I may filter them out via logcheck?  Here is an example of the current log entry:

> Aug 16 00:00:00  nagios[4711]: CURRENT SERVICE STATE: ;Apache Servers;CRITICAL;HARD;4;CRITICAL - Socket timeout

And what I would like to accomplish is:

> Aug 16 00:00:00 nagios[4711]: CURRENT SERVICE STATE: ACKNOWLEDGED; Apache Servers;CRITICAL;HARD;4;CRITICAL - Socket timeout

or something similar.

I will also be posting this to Nagios forums so please disregard any cross posts.

Comment: This would require some source-hacking

Comment: yea, that's what I thought.  It may not be worth my time to make this work.  Thank you for the response.

Comment: Have you looked at PagerDuty?  They do a great job of handling the notifications part of monitoring and they integrate with nagios cleanly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way of managing alerts is pretty odd. I mean, Nagios has its own notification mechanism that works pretty well, you don't need to check the logs. But if you want to keep on with your approach, I can see 3 solutions:

- Patching the source. This is really not the route I would take. Moreover, if you change the logs format you will end up breaking the reporting pages, since they use the logs as source of informations
- creating a fake contact with a notification script that parses the event and write to a log file with all the informations you want/need
- the same as above, but using an Event Handler (I would go with this)

some info from Nagios documentation:

- https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/eventhandlers.html
- https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/notifications.html

Comment: thank you for the information, yea I know we use a weird way of logging, it's just a nice catch all for everything going on on our systems.  I may try one of those methods posted above, for now I am just going to ignore it.  Thank you for the response